# What are the primary differences between solana-validator and solana-test-validator?

Tags: validator, solana-test-validator

There seems to be two different validator binaries: `solana-validator` in `validator/src/main.rs`, and `solana-test-validator` in `validator/src/bin/solana-test-validator.rs`. What are the main differences between the two?

Naively I would have assumed that the test validator would simply be the regular validator with different flags passed in as default, but it seems like the two differ quite substantially in implementation and flags.

Answer (score 1):

`solana-validator` is what you would normally run for a node on any of the public clusters like `mainnet/testnet` etc. It has full functionality built into it.

On the other hand, `solana-test-validator` is used for running a local instance of validator on localhost for local development and testing. It is very lightweight comparatively and has minimal functionality built into it.

Hopes this answers your question?

Comment: Right I'm aware that `solana-test-validator` is for testing, but I'm wondering if there's a high-level summary of the actual feature differences between the two, and what the motivation was for having two binaries instead of using a single binary and having `solana-test-validator` simply call the full binary.